# Cassandra/Spark showing incorrect entries count for large table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use spark to process a large cassandra table (~402 million entries and 84 columns) but I am getting inconsistent results. Initially the requirement was to copy some columns from this table to another table. After copying the data, I noticed that some entries in the new table were missing. To verify that I took count of the large source table but I am getting different values each time. I tried the queries on a smaller table (~7 million records) and the results were fine.

Initially, I attempted to take count using pyspark. Here is my pyspark script:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Datacopy App").getOrCreate() 
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table=sourcetable, keyspace=sourcekeyspace).load().cache() 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data") 
query = ("select count(1) from data " ) 
vgDF = spark.sql(query) 
vgDF.show(10)
```

Spark submit command is as follows:

```
~/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.128.0.18:7077 --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.1-s_2.11 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host="10.128.1.1,10.128.1.2,10.128.1.3" --conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=1" --conf spark.local.dir=/media/db/ --executor-memory 10G --num-executors=6 --executor-cores=2 --total-executor-cores 18 pyspark_script.py
```

The above spark submit process takes ~90 minutes to complete. I ran it three times and here are the counts I got:

- Spark iteration 1:  402273852
- Spark iteration 2:  402273884
- Spark iteration 3:  402274209

Spark does not show any error or exception during the entire process. I ran the same query in cqlsh thrice and got different results again:

- Cqlsh iteration 1:   402273598
- Cqlsh iteration 2:   402273499
- Cqlsh iteration 3:   402273515

I am unable to find out why I am getting different outcomes from the same query. Cassandra system logs (/var/log/cassandra/system.log) has shown the following error message just once:

```
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:3] 2018-02-27 09:48:23,592 CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[SSTableBatchOpen:3,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Stats component is missing for sstable /media/db/datakeyspace/sensordata1-acfa7880acba11e782fd9bf3ae460699/mc-58617-big
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:460) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:375) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$4.run(SSTableReader.java:536) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Versions:

- Cassandra 3.9.
- Spark 2.1.0.
- Datastax's spark-cassandra-connector 2.0.1
- Scala version 2.11

Cluster:

- Spark setup with 3 workers and 1 master node.
- 3 worker nodes also have a cassandra cluster installed.
- Each worker node has 8 CPU cores and 40 GB RAM.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this not a live database (being read to or written from by other applications/processes)?

Comment: No, at the moment, I am the only one using the database.

Comment: Did you had some trouble while writting the inital data? By trouble I mean some network issues. Or even a cassandra not went down? Did you repaired your tables afterwards? Can you tell us something more about the table definition (e.g. replica factor and/or compaction strategy).

Comment: Or is it maybe just a silly thing like a TTL which expires?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Cassandra is deployed on gcloud VMs so network was not problematic. The problem is related to read consistency level of cassandra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark Cassandra connector default read consistency is "LOCAL_ONE" and default write consistency is "LOCAL_QUORUM", so it is possible to read partial data before full repair with that defaults. You can read "ONE" for the node that fail to write data, but that was not error because other 2 replicas success. So you should either set BOTH levels to QUORUM or one of them to ALL

```
config("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level", "LOCAL_QUORUM").
config("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "LOCAL_QUORUM").
```

The default CQL shell level is also ONE, so you should also increase it:

```
cqlsh> CONSISTENCY QUORUM
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Setting read consistency to ALL fixed the problem. However, the query time has increased by an hour which is a problem.

Does this mean my replicas are not in sync?

Iniitally my cassandra setup consisted of only one node. Then after a while I added two more nodes and changed the replication factor to 2. After that I ran nodetool repair. According to my understanding, the nodes should share data passively and remain in sync.

How can I debug this further? Also, is running "nodetool repair" once enough or do I need to run it periodically?

Comment: ALL consistency means that client should wait for results from all replicas in case of read. So it is slower. it will wait for confirmation that data was stored at commit log all all replicas for writes:
If consistency is not ALL, some replicas could fail two save data and this is not an error. the full consistency will be restored asynchronously, or by "noodtool repair" command. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html