# DataFrame and RDD count method returns different size for every query. Why?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, rdd

There is a cassandra table and I get it by DF and RDD so as to count row. But count method returns different size for every process of counting. Why ? How can I get consistent and true result ?

```
val productDF= spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("keyspace" -> "test", "table" -> "product")).load()

productDF.count()  // 93789122
productDF.count()  // 93789456
productDF.count()  // 93789274

val productRDD = sc.cassandraTable("test", "product")

productRDD.count()  // 93789632
productRDD.count()  // 93789075
productRDD.count()  // 93789245
```

I tried collect() method, but I get memory exception.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081803/cassandra-spark-showing-incorrect-entries-count-for-large-table